# read dynamic data from json

Tags: javascript, json, html

Read json `'var dt='{"var1":"1","var2":"2"}';'` data every one second, in this json data I've given static data which is 1,2, but in my program var1, var2 value will change dynamically. I need to post the dynamic data in text boxes, I've tried set interval function, no use:( help needed,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});           
  var dt='{"var1":"1","var2":"2"}';
  var data=$.parseJSON(dt);
  if (data.var1) {
    $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.var1);
  }
  if (data.var2) {
    $('#C2-Cycle').val(data.var2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `JSON.parse(dt);` instead of `$.parseJSON(dt);`. If the `var1` and `var2` changes, you need to use:

```
$.each(dt, function (key, value) {
  // key => var1 or whatever is latest
  // value => the value stored in the key
  if (key == "var1") {
    $('#C1-Cycle').val(dt[key]);
  }
  if (key == "var2") {
    $('#C2-Cycle').val(dt[key]);
  }
});
```

If based on the number you get, you change the `Cx` value, then you can do something like this:

```
$.each(dt, function (key, value) {
  // key => var1 or whatever is latest
  // value => the value stored in the key
  $('#C' + key.replace('var', '') + '-Cycle').val(dt[key]);
});
```

#### Updated from Comments and Fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    var winterval = setInterval(function () {
        var dt='{"var1":"1","var2":"2"}';
        var data = JSON.parse(dt);
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $('#C' + key.replace('var', '') + '-Cycle').val(data[key]);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="C1-Cycle" />
</div>
<hr />
<div>
    <input type="text" id="C2-Cycle" />
</div>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});           
    setInterval(function () {
  var dt='{"var1":"datablock.value[0]","var2":"datablock.value[1]"}';
       var data=JSON.parse(dt);
       $.each(dt, function (key, value) {
     if (key == "var1") {
    $('#C1-Cycle').val(data[key]);
     }
     if (key == "var2") {
    $('#C2-Cycle').val(data[key]);
     }
   });
     }, 1000);
   });` for every one sec i should refresh or re assign  value of datablock.value[0],  this datablock will be in PLC, can you follow this?

Comment: Can you please update your code in the question? Not as a comment?

Comment: C1-cycle, c2-cycle are just textbox id., I've did the same thing with   `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            setInterval(function () {
                $.get("IO.html", function (result) {
                    $('#counter').text(result.trim());
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>` but in this example we are passing just one value, and IO.html file has just one line `:="Data_block_int".value[0]:`, I'm trying to do the same thing with mutiple value..

Comment: Check out my page http://jsfiddle.net/1mmwfy9q/2/, json variables are example, I'll get the real value from PLC machine, That will change every one second, i can access the PLC data by using `:="Data_block_int".value[0]:` this syntax, It retrieves the values but in static manner, If i refresh the values are updated, but I'm using Collapsible panel so refresh whole page is annoying..,

Comment: @RJ10 Is your web response cached?

Comment: yes., but in static manner.,  this JS (https://jsfiddle.net/qn1v0L26/ function gave the exact result, but in label also with just one value, I'm trying  to do the same with multiple values, I'm able to get the result but set intervel function not working.,  I'm PLC progmmer.

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar https://jsfiddle.net/qn1v0L26/ Here, I did't use any variable, I directly get the output from one html file, so reassigning the values to variables are not necessary, setintervel function retrieve the result from one page in every sec, I directly post the result in label, but here that fails, setintervel function have not reassign values to variables every one sec

Answer (score 0):

Since `var1, var2` are changing, move/copy this code to the place where you change `var1, var2`. So the same event will do the work for you.